# Is there a way to plot the radius of a circle that passes by three points?

Tags: plotting, geometry

Let $x$ and $y$ be defined such that

```
x=(((-3 + r) r^2 + a^2 (1 + r)) Csc[θ])/(a (-1 + r))

y=Sqrt[(a^2 (a^2 (1 + r)^2 + 2 r^2 (-3 + r^2)) + 
 a^4 (-1 + r)^2 Cos[θ]^2 - ((-3 + r) r^2 + 
    a^2 (1 + r))^2 Csc[θ]^2)/(a^2 (-1 + r)^2)]
```

Where for each value of $0<a<1$ and $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ we can plot a  **circle like figure** using

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, y}, {x, -y}}, {r, -10, 10}]
```

Now, let $R_{s}$ to be the radius of a circle that passes the three points: (A) the top point of the circle like figure, (B) the bottom point of the circle like figure and (C) the right most point of the circle like figure.

[image]

My question is there a way to plot $R_{s}$ in terms of $a$ and $\theta$?

For example

```
ContourPlot[Subscript[R, s], {a, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, π/2}]
```

How would this look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post this is as a separate answer based on the comment made to my other answer by OP (rather than the title to the question).

The function to find the radius is inefficient and I have used interpolation to approximate the desired contour plot (assuming I have understood the comment correctly):

```
x[a_, r_, t_] := (((-3 + r) r^2 + a^2 (1 + r)) Csc[t])/(a (-1 + r))

y[a_, r_, t_] := 
 Sqrt[(a^2 (a^2 (1 + r)^2 + 2 r^2 (-3 + r^2)) + 
     a^4 (-1 + r)^2 Cos[t]^2 - ((-3 + r) r^2 + a^2 (1 + r))^2 Csc[
        t]^2)/(a^2 (-1 + r)^2)]
tp[a_, t_] := 
 Quiet@Module[{cs, c, ra, 
    top = u /. Solve[D[y[a, u, t], u] == 0, u, Reals], 
    yz = v /. Solve[y[a, v, t] == 0, v, Reals], xm, pts, tops}, 
   tops = Last[SortBy[{x[a, #, t], y[a, #, t]} & /@ top, Last]];
   xm = Last@Sort[x[a, #, t] & /@ yz];
   pts = {{xm, 0}, tops, {1, -1} tops};
   cs = Circumsphere[pts];
   {c, ra} = List @@ cs;
   ra
   ]
tab = {{##}, tp[##]} & @@@ 
   Tuples[{Range[0.1, 1, 0.1], Range[0.1, Pi/2, 0.1]}];
if = Interpolation[tab];
ContourPlot[if[x, y], {x, 0.1, 1}, {y, 0.1, Pi/2}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Table[{Pi j/180, j}, {j, 10, 90, 10}]}, 
 BaseStyle -> 12, FrameLabel -> {"a", "\[Theta]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why does this error appear "ContourPlot::optx : Unknown option PlotLegends"?

Comment: @MrDi what version of Mma are you using? I used version 11.0.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 7

Comment: Is this the reason its not working?

Comment: @MrDi I am sorry I did not appreciate this. Remove `PlotLegend` and you should get plot. I suggest playing around, I am off to bed. :)

Comment: @MrDi I do not think `Circumsphere` was in version 7. If you write your own  code to find circumcentre for three points (or search site) then perhaps you can adapt. All the best :)

Comment: Its Ok, I think my friend has version 11 and I am going to use his computer. Just one question does the plot take long time to load?

Comment: @MrDi yes but using the interpolating function was coarser grid was my attempt to speed it up. Sorry have to sleep:)

Answer (score 4):

```
points = {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {5, 1}};
circleParameters[points_] := 
     Block[{x0, y0, r}, {r, x0, y0} /. 
     First@Solve[points /. {x_, y_} :> (x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 == r]]

Module[{r, x0, y0},
 {r, x0, y0} = circleParameters[points];
 Show[
  ContourPlot[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 == r, {x, -2, 6}, {y, -2, 6}],
  Graphics@{Red, PointSize@Large, Point@points}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
x[a_, r_, t_] := (((-3 + r) r^2 + a^2 (1 + r)) Csc[t])/(a (-1 + r))

y[a_, r_, t_] := 
 Sqrt[(a^2 (a^2 (1 + r)^2 + 2 r^2 (-3 + r^2)) + 
     a^4 (-1 + r)^2 Cos[t]^2 - ((-3 + r) r^2 + a^2 (1 + r))^2 Csc[
        t]^2)/(a^2 (-1 + r)^2)]
tp[a_, t_] := Module[{
   cs, c, ra,
   top = u /. Solve[D[y[a, u, t], u] == 0, u, Reals],
   yz = v /. Solve[y[a, v, t] == 0, v, Reals], xm, pts, tops},
  tops = Last[SortBy[{x[a, #, t], y[a, #, t]} & /@ top, Last]];
  xm = Last@Sort[x[a, #, t] & /@ yz];
  pts = {{xm, 0}, tops, {1, -1} tops};
  cs = Circumsphere[pts];
  {c, ra} = List @@ cs;
  Graphics[{Gray, cs, Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts], Green, 
    Point[c], {Purple, Line[{c, #}]} & /@ pts, Black, 
    Text[Framed[ra], {xm/2, 0}, {0, -1}]}]
  ]
vis[a_, b_] := 
 Show[Quiet@tp[a, b], 
  ParametricPlot[{#, {1, -1} #} &@{x[a, r, b], y[a, r, b]}, {r, 0, 
    10}], Frame -> True]
```

Visualizing some examples:

```
Manipulate[vis[a, b],
 {a, {0.9, 0.95, 0.99}}, {b, Range[0.5, 1.5, 0.2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for response. What I am asking for is a contour plot of $R_{s}$ in terms of $a$ and $\theta$. See this picture http://i.imgur.com/fj9LwFI.png of a plot from a paper where the authors plot $R_{s}$. In the picture $i$ represents $\theta$ measured in degrees and $a/M$ represents $a$.

Answer (score 0):

If you define `x` and `y` as functions:

```
x[a_, r_, t_] := (((-3 + r) r^2 + a^2 (1 + r)) Csc[t])/(a (-1 + r))

y[a_, r_, t_] := Sqrt[(a^2 (a^2 (1 + r)^2 + 2 r^2 (-3 + r^2)) + 
    a^4 (-1 + r)^2 Cos[t]^2 - ((-3 + r) r^2 + a^2 (1 + r))^2
    Csc[t]^2)/(a^2 (-1 + r)^2)]
```

You can plot the circle with:

```
Manipulate[
    ParametricPlot[{{x[a, r, t], y[a, r, t]},{x[a, r, t], -y[a, r, t]}},
    {r, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1],
    {{t, 1.}, 0, Pi/2}, {{a, .4}, .01, .99}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for response but this is not what I am asking for. I want to plot the radius of a circle that passes by the three points (A), (B) and (C).

Answer (score 0):

ok, so you have the parametric plot:

```
pp = ParametricPlot[{{x, y}, {x, -y}}, {r, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can get the desired points from this plot:

```
pts = Flatten[Cases[pp, Line[pts__] :> pts, Infinity], 1];
xmax = First@MaximalBy[pts, First];
ymax = First@MaximalBy[pts, Last];
ymin = First@MinimalBy[pts, Last];
```

Having these points we can generate a circumsphere:

```
circumsphere = Graphics[{
   Circumsphere[{xmax, ymax, ymin}],
   PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{xmax, ymax, ymin}]
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Having the circumsphere, we can get its center:

```
{center} = Cases[circumsphere, Sphere[center_, r_] :> center, Infinity];
```

And finally we can plot all of our information together:

```
Show[
 pp,
 circumsphere,
 Graphics[{
   Line[{center, xmax}],
   Line[{center, ymax}],
   Line[{center, ymin}]
   }],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for response. What I am asking for is a contour plot of $R_{s}$ in terms of $a$ and $\theta$. See this picture http://i.imgur.com/fj9LwFI.png of a plot from a paper where the authors plot $R_{s}$. In the picture $i$ represents $\theta$ measured in degrees and $a/M$ represents $a$.

Comment: @MrDi OK, but now that you know how to retrieve $R_s$ for parameters $(a, \theta)$, perhaps you can also create the contour plot. Step 1) Turn this solution into a function, 2) Give it to `ContourPlot`.

Comment: I did but it takes very long and no result shows up. Did you try it? Did you get similar result?

Comment: @MrDi It's not really built to be fast, I would first try to generate a table of values in the format required by `ListContourPlot`. I'd inspect the table to see that the values look right, and then I'd use `ListContourPlot` instead. I have not tried it.

Comment: @MrDi From your comment to ubpdqn we now know why this isn't working for you; you are using Mathematica 7 and `Circumsphere` requires at least Mathematica 10. (Always mention this when you ask a question, since that version is more than eight years old now.)

Comment: OK thank you. I am going to get Mathematica 11 and try you code.